# MongoDB race conditions or concurency issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6

I have the following code in my chat application based on NodeJS and MongoDB to change admin for room:

```
export function setAdmin(room, user) {
  const userGuid = getGuid(user);
  if (room.users && room.users.length) {
    // filter current and new
    room.users = room.users.filter(guid => 
      guid !== room.adminGuid && guid !== userGuid
    );
  } else {
    room.users = [];
  }

  room.users.push(userGuid);
  room.adminGuid = userGuid;

  return roomsCollection.save(room, { w: 1 });
}
```

Each room have only 2 users: admin and customer.
To update several rooms:

```
  const rooms = await roomsCollection.find({ adminGuid: currentAdminGuid  }).toArray();
  for (const room of rooms) {
    await setAdmin(room, newAdminUser);
  }
```

I had some problems under highload with my application. They were resolved with help of indexes.

But after, working with MongoDB dump I found out that I have rooms with 3 users guids in `room.users` array. I think that `save` works as `update` for exist document, but how it updates array?  If `$set`, why I have such 3 users rooms. Any thoughts how it would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

save() behaves as insert if document does not exist. You have to use update() with {upsert: false}

- some resources to update array: [Array Query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-array/), [array Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/)
- simple tutorial to nest array inside document, [here](http://tgrall.github.io/blog/2015/04/21/mongodb-playing-with-arrays/)
- advanced example of dealing with multiple nested array, [here](https://www.nodechef.com/docs/cloud-search/updates-documents-nested-in-arrays)